# page-query is not working inside component in Gridsome

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, gridsome

If use `<page-query>` inside the index is working, but when I use it inside a component I get an error of "edges undefined".
Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's normal, In Gridsome when you query inside a component instead of `<page-query>` you should use `<static-query>`.
When using posts as alias (for example), your data will be available at `$page.posts` usually but if you are using `<static-query>` instead it will be available at `$static.posts`

As you can read [here](https://gridsome.org/docs/querying-data/)